# Openstack : instance of windows server 2019 from iso failed because windows can't be installed to this disk...whY?

Tags: openstack, windows-server-2019, iso

I have a test lab with Openstack Victoria (1 controller node, 1 block storage node (cinder) and 1 compute node).

I use horizon dashboard to create my instance in order to install windows server 2019 from my custom iso (it includes virtio drivers).
I can boot from iso and see all the attached block storage bootable volumes as available disks.

Unfortunately, when I tried to install windows, I have the message "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu."

What am I missing? What's wrong?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: My guess is that virtio is not used, or not used properly. https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/windows-image.html is an example workflow of creating your own Windows image from an ISO. It doesn't install an OpenStack instance but uses a libvirt VM - I don't think that's relevant though. Steps 3 to 8 imply that you have to explicitly tell the Windows installer to use virtio drivers for both storage and NICs. Perhaps you can transfer these instructions to your case?